# Visual C++ 2015 won't compile templated code

Tags: c++, templates, visual-c++, visual-studio-2015

The following will not compile with VS 2015:

```
template <typename T, typename U>
struct Tree {
    struct Node {};
};

template <typename T>
struct Thing : public Tree<T, int> {
    typename Tree<T, int>::Node* foo();
};

template <typename T>
typename Tree<T, int>::Node* Thing<T>::foo() {return nullptr;}

int main() {}
```

But if I remove the second template parameter of `Tree` it compiles, and if I define `foo()` inside the `Thing<T>` class it compiles.  So this is a VS bug right?  How do modify the above so that it compiles in VS2015, without defining `foo()` inside the class?  The error message states "unable to match function definition to an existing declaration".

Comment: You should tell us what the exact error message states.  Also, it doesn't compiler here either: http://ideone.com/YZVMJp

Comment: [The following code](http://rextester.com/GUOPH58290) seems to be accepted by VS

Comment: I don't get it then.  My Visual Studio 2015 won't compile exactly what is above.  But if I remove the template U everywhere it does compile.

Comment: [Here's one more](http://rextester.com/FYI54511) alternative

Comment: Ah!  Thank you for this alternative.  Now it compiles.  I don't know why my VS2015 needs it, but it works now at least.

Answer (score 1):

I believe, there is a typo in your code. The following compiles:

```
template <typename T, typename U>
struct Tree {
    struct Node {};
};

template <typename T>
struct Thing : public Tree<T, int> {
    typename Tree<T, int>::Node* foo();
};

template <typename T>
typename Tree<T, int>::Node* Thing<T>::foo() {return nullptr;}
```

Note return type of the function.

Comment: I typed it wrong here, but I typed it correctly in my program.  The above does not compile with my Visual Studio 2015.  The error message states "unable to match function definition to an existing declaration".  But if I remove the second template parameter of Tree it compiles, and if I define foo() inside the Thing<T> class it compiles.

Answer (score 0):

Only first template is really needed. Updates made compiler creating a template to the end of life of Your program. Some not up to date courses still teach to create every new Template to any method You are using, but it's simply not needed. So it's not just a VS "bug".

Answer (score 0):

```
template <typename T, typename U>
struct Tree {
    struct Node {};
};

template <typename T>
struct Thing : public Tree<T, int> {
    typedef typename Tree<T, int>::Node Node;
    Node* foo();
};

template <typename T>
typename Thing<T>::Node*  Thing<T>::foo() {return nullptr;}

int main() {
    Thing<int> i;
}
```

You can help reader to.